# Determine the accuracy of Poisson approximation to birthday problem

Tags: probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, poissons-equation, birthday

I'm currently doing an exploration of the Birthday Problem, and noticed that the formula given to calculate the probability for $m$ people in a  room is:

$$1-\frac{365!}{365^m (365-m)!}$$

And this can be approximated by the Poisson approximation:

$$1-e^{-\lambda}$$

Where $$\lambda = np = \frac{m(m-1)}{730},$$ for $m$ number of people in a room.

I have calculated the probabilities for $m = 1$ to $m = 365$ and they form a scatter plot.

My question is, how could one go about calculating the accuracy of the Poisson Approximation to this probability?

So far I looked into the Z-test for two proportions, but I'm not sure if that is an appropriate test or should I be plotting two scatter plots, one for each formula?

The idea here is that I want to identify if the Poisson function is a good way to approximate this probability.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In comparing two functions, in this case defined for discrete arguments $m=0,1,\ldots$, there are many metrics that could be applied.  Perhaps you'd be satisfied by tabulating the values for a handful of arguments?

Comment: @hardmath I updated the question - i have tabulated these values from 1 through to 365. Lets say if i take m=23, the probability using the original equation yields 0.50729723432396, but by using the Poisson Approximation i get 0.50000175218271. I think what I want to find is how good this poisson function can approximate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean by calculating the accuracy. If you want to know the error you made when calculating $f(m)$ with the function $\tilde f(m)$, simply calculate $$|f(m)-\tilde f(m)|$$ which gives you the absolute error of your approxumation. The relative error is $$\frac{|f(m)-\tilde f(m)|}{|f(m)|}.$$

Comment: Just edited my question, I think I was a bit vague initially, sorry!

Comment: @agqy28 Still, the error you are reffering to here is not a probabilistic construct. You are talking about two functions that are approximately equal, there is no probability, no hypotheses here. My answer still stands.